# Linking text to another page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to redirect to another view in my application when user clicks to the hyperlinked text. I wrote the code like this:

```
<p class="mb-0">
    <a href="~/Views/Account/ApprovalValidation.cshtml">I want to check approval</a>
</p>
```

But it's not opening the page and returns an error saying that view cannot found that location.

Can anyone show me what I did wrong?

Here is a picture of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Url.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method is the most convenient way of generating outgoing links:

```
<p class="mb-0">
    <a href="@Url.Action("ApprovalValidation", "Account")">I want to check approval</a>
</p>
```

Also you can use `href="/Account/ApprovalValidation"` or `href="~/Account/ApprovalValidation"`. Starting from MVC 4, Razor automatically detects attributes that begin with `~/` and automatically inserts the `@Href` or `@Url` call for you.

See the following article for additional information:
[Tilde notation maps to the original URLs by using IIS URL rewrite in ASP.NET Web Pages Razor V3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/tilde-notation-maps-original-url)